# How to initialize List, that is in struct

Tags: c#, struct, initialization

Here I declare struct outside main

```
    struct webDataStructure
    {
        public string title;
        public string mainLink;
        public string numberOfPages;
        public List<string> secondaryLinks;
    }
```

Inside main I initialize structure

```
webDataStructure[] webData = new webDataStructure[400];
```

And I initialize it inside main in for loop

```
webData[i].secondaryLinks = new List<string>(35);
```

The problem is that Count of List is still 0, should be 35

Comment: The [`List<T>(int)` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) only lets you specify the _initial capacity_, not the number of elements to create. What strings do you want to be in the list? Are you sure you need a struct as opposed to a class?

Comment: I may use class also, I will store links in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed size collection, why use a `List` and not an `Array`?

```
struct webDataStructure
{
    public string title;
    public string mainLink;
    public string numberOfPages;
    public string[] secondaryLinks;
}

webData[i].secondaryLinks = new string[35];
```